# Datagrid combobox column populated with values from another column in the same datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `List<Coefficients>` in memory. The `Coefficients` class has a `string Name` as ID, and a lot of other fields (some names and identifying details have been changed to protect the privacy of the code). The `DataGrid` code is like this:

```
<DataGrid
    Name="coefficientList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data.CoefficientList, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Priority, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now the elements in the datagrid must reference another element in the same collection, so I have a new field in the `Coefficients` class: `string ReferencedName`. This is the string ID of the referenced element in the collection. So I would like to have a new column in the datagrid to select the value of the referenced element via a combobox, and that combobox needs to be populated with the `Name` column of the same datagrid.

How can I achieve that? So far I have tried something like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox
                SelectedValue="{Binding ReferencedName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                    Path=Data.NameList, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

where `NameList` is

```
public IEnumerable<string> NameList
{
    get
    {
        return CoefficientList.Select(c => c.Name);
    }
}
```

but anything I have tried so far always gives a combobox with no options, and errors in the output window like

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Data'
>   property not found on 'object' ''DataGrid'
>   (Name='coefficientList')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Data.NameList; DataItem='DataGrid'
>   (Name='coefficientList'); target element is 'ComboBox'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data.NameList` is a property of `DataContext` object. change binding path

```
Path=DataContext.Data.NameList
```

Comment: So easy, yet so elusive! Thank you very much!

Comment: yes, often forget it myself  when use `RelativeSource`